# How can I make a led blink at different frequencies upon button switch?

Tags: led, atmega

I'm trying to make a led blink at 3 different frequencies, upon successive keypresses. My problem right now it's that it's only blinking 2 times and I don't understand why. D6 is LED, D4 is the test output. Here it's my main function:

```
   /*********************************************
Project : Test software
**********************************************
Chip type: ATmega164A
Clock frequency: 20 MHz
Compilers:  CVAVR 2.x
*********************************************/

#include <mega164a.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <delay.h>  
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "defs.h"    

//*************************************************************************************************
//*********** BEGIN SERIAL STUFF (interrupt-driven, generated by Code Wizard) *********************
//*************************************************************************************************

#ifndef RXB8
#define RXB8 1
#endif

#ifndef TXB8
#define TXB8 0
#endif

#ifndef UPE
#define UPE 2
#endif

#ifndef DOR
#define DOR 3
#endif

#ifndef FE
#define FE 4
#endif

#ifndef UDRE
#define UDRE 5
#endif

#ifndef RXC
#define RXC 7
#endif

#define FRAMING_ERROR (1<<FE)
#define PARITY_ERROR (1<<UPE)
#define DATA_OVERRUN (1<<DOR)
#define DATA_REGISTER_EMPTY (1<<UDRE)
#define RX_COMPLETE (1<<RXC)


/*
 * Timer 1 Output Compare A interrupt is used to blink LED
 */
interrupt [TIM1_COMPA] void timer1_compa_isr(void)
{
LED1 = ~LED1; // invert LED    
}                                  

/*
 * main function of program
 */
void main (void)
{          


    Init_initController();  // this must be the first "init" action/call!
    #asm("sei")             // enable interrupts
    LED1 = 1;               // initial state, will be changed by timer 1
    while(TRUE)
    {
        wdogtrig();         // call often else processor will reset
                 

        if(SW1 == 0)        // pressed
        {
            delay_ms(30);   // debounce switch
            if(SW1 == 0)    
            {                // LED will blink slow or fast
                while(SW1==0){
                    wdogtrig();    // wait for release
                    }
                // alternate between values and values/4 for OCR1A register
                // 4C40H / 4 = 1310H
                // new frequency = old frequency * 4
                if(OCR1AH == 0x4C)  
                    {TCNT1H=0; TCNT1L=0; OCR1AH = 0x13; OCR1AL = 0x10;}
                else     
                    {TCNT1H=0; TCNT1L=0; OCR1AH = 0x4C; OCR1AL = 0x40;}            
            }                
        }                                       
        
        // measure time intervals on oscilloscope connected to pin TESTP
        for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
            TESTP = 1;
            delay_us(1);
            TESTP = 0;   // may check accuracy of 1us interval on oscilloscope     
        }
    } 

            
}// end main loop
```

And here it's the init.c function:

```
/* initialization file */

#include <mega164a.h>
#include "defs.h"
                                          

/*
 * most intialization values are generated using Code Wizard and depend on clock value
 */
void Init_initController(void)
{
// Crystal Oscillator division factor: 1
#pragma optsize-
CLKPR=0x80;
CLKPR=0x00;
#ifdef _OPTIMIZE_SIZE_
#pragma optsize+
#endif

// Input/Output Ports initialization
// Port A initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
PORTA=0x00;
DDRA=0x00;

// Port B initialization
PORTB=0x00;
DDRB=0x00;

// Port C initialization
PORTC=0x00;
DDRC=0x00;

// Port D initialization
PORTD=0b00100000; // D.5 needs pull-up resistor
DDRD= 0b01010000; // D.6 is LED, D.4 is test output

// Timer/Counter 0 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer 0 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=FFh
// OC0 output: Disconnected
TCCR0A=0x00;
TCCR0B=0x00;
TCNT0=0x00;
OCR0A=0x00;
OCR0B=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 1 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: 19.531 kHz = CLOCK/256
// Mode: CTC top=OCR1A
// OC1A output: Discon.
// OC1B output: Discon.
// Noise Canceler: Off
// Input Capture on Falling Edge
// Timer 1 Overflow Interrupt: Off
// Input Capture Interrupt: Off
// Compare A Match Interrupt: On
// Compare B Match Interrupt: Off

TCCR1A=0x00;
TCCR1B=0x0D;
TCNT1H=0x00;
TCNT1L=0x00;
ICR1H=0x00;
ICR1L=0x00;

// 1 sec = 19531 counts = 4C41H counts, from 0 to 4C40 
// 4C40H = 4CH (MSB) and 40H (LSB)
OCR1AH=0x4C;
OCR1AL=0x40;

OCR1BH=0x00;
OCR1BL=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 2 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer2 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC2A output: Disconnected
// OC2B output: Disconnected
ASSR=0x00;
TCCR2A=0x00;
TCCR2B=0x00;
TCNT2=0x00;
OCR2A=0x00;
OCR2B=0x00;

// External Interrupt(s) initialization
// INT0: Off
// INT1: Off
// INT2: Off
// Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT0-7: Off
// Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT8-15: Off
// Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT16-23: Off
// Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT24-31: Off
EICRA=0x00;
EIMSK=0x00;
PCICR=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 0,1,2 Interrupt(s) initialization
TIMSK0=0x00;
TIMSK1=0x02;
TIMSK2=0x00;

// USART0 initialization
// Communication Parameters: 8 Data, 1 Stop, No Parity
// USART0 Receiver: On
// USART0 Transmitter: On
// USART0 Mode: Asynchronous
// USART0 Baud rate: 9600
UCSR0A=0x00;
UCSR0B=0xD8;
UCSR0C=0x06;
UBRR0H=0x00;
UBRR0L=0x81;

// USART1 initialization
// USART1 disabled
UCSR1B=0x00;


// Analog Comparator initialization
// Analog Comparator: Off
// Analog Comparator Input Capture by Timer/Counter 1: Off
ACSR=0x80;
ADCSRB=0x00;
DIDR1=0x00;

// Watchdog Timer initialization
// Watchdog Timer Prescaler: OSC/2048  
#pragma optsize-
#asm("wdr")
// Write 2 consecutive values to enable watchdog
// this is NOT a mistake !
WDTCSR=0x18;
WDTCSR=0x08;
#ifdef _OPTIMIZE_SIZE_
#pragma optsize+
#endif

}
```

Defs.h file:

```
/* definitions / defines file */
#define DEFS_H

#define SW_VERSION      13   /* i.e. major.minor software version nbr. */

#ifndef NULL
#define NULL  0
#endif
        
// logix ...
#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0 
#define DUMMY   0

#define wdogtrig()          #asm("wdr") // call often if Watchdog timer enabled

#define CR              0x0D
#define LF              0x0A  

#define LED1 PORTD.6        // PORTx is used for output
#define SW1 PIND.5          // PINx is used for input
#define TESTP PORTD.4       // test bit durations
#include "funct.h"
```

And this is how my minimalistic setup looks like:

[image]

Comment: A bit too minimalist I think. Please show the complete schematic including power supply, decoupling caps, reset circuit etc. And put a suitable resistor in series with the LED to limit I/O port current.

Comment: @Bruce this can't be done without what you've said?

Comment: @Bruce I only need a led and the microcontroller in order to have a led blinking, because right now my main problem is that it's not blinking at a certain frequency, it's blinking 2 times instead of 3 times

Comment: Perhaps there is an error in your code, but if the hardware is not working properly you code won't either. Make sure you have decoupling caps on the power supply and reset pin pulled up, or it might fail to work properly (freeze, reset periodically, go crazy etc.). If you can't be bothered doing that then I can't bothered reviewing your code.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'm not an expert in this, I'm just a noob trying to learn, so I don't know how to do what you've said to me...I'm using a simulator so it will not be a problem with reset and things

Comment: Where do you define ’LED1’ and what is it defined as? Stuff like ’LED1 = 1’ is suspect. You can't assign values directly to individual bits, you'd have to manually manipulate the bits in the output port byte.

Comment: @Unimportant in the defs.h, I've edited the code now to see it

Comment: If your circuit were actually wired as you've shown, either your LED and/or your microcontroller pin drive will soon die if they haven't already.

Comment: @Reinderien I'm doing this in simulations mode only, not in real life. What can I do in order to have a good schematic where I simulate a led blinking at a certain time?

Comment: What is your simulation software?

Comment: @Reinderien  SimulIDE, it's a free one. I'm developing the code in CodeVisionAVR

Comment: Based on https://www.electronicsforu.com/buyers-guides/simulide-simulating-electronic-circuits SimulIDE can definitely support resistors. You should wire your circuit to be as realistic as SimulIDE will allow.

Comment: @Reinderien add a 100-ohm resistor to the led before the ground,no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by creating a function:

```
void handle_press() {
        int i;
        int state = 0;
int delay[] = { 150, 250, 500 };
  /* blink three times at the rate specified for the current state */
  for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    LED1 = 1;
    delay_ms(delay[state]);
    LED1 = 0;
    delay_ms(delay[state]);
  }
  
  /* then wait another second */
  delay_ms(1000);
  
  /* update state */
  state = (state + 1);
  if (state == 3) {
    state = 0;
  }
}
void main (void)
{          
unsigned char temp,i;

    Init_initController();  // this must be the first "init" action/call!
    #asm("sei")             // enable interrupts
    LED1 = 1;               // initial state, will be changed by timer 1
    while(TRUE)
    {
        wdogtrig();         // call often else processor will reset
    
       if (SW1 == 0) {
      handle_press();
        }                  

    } 

            
}// end main loop
```

Comment: The code in your function would work the same if it were in side the while loop in main.  It isn't the fact that it is a function that makes it work, it is the fact  that you the correct code in the function that matters.